# Parse/Extract JSON data in CSV file

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I've hundreds of rows in CSV file while contains JSON data like below. Below is a sample of each row.

```json
{"Id":"value","RecordType":"value","CreationTime":"value","Operation":"value"}
```

I tried to convert the same into CSV as below but no luck as of now.

Expected format of CSV file:

```
id      RecordType  CreationTime    Operation
value   value            value           value
```

```
$properties = @('Id', 'RecordType', 'CreationTime', 'Operation')
(Get-Content -Path-to_CSVfile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json) |
    Select-Object -Property $properties |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $path-to-new-csv-file
```

If someone has an idea about this please help me. I tried `ConvertTo-Json` but it's failing with error:

> ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: "id"

Here are the first two rows of CSV data.

```
{"Id":"ac325bc9-97f0-4b29-8fc4-90b80b945f6c","RecordType":20,"CreationTime":"2019-09-14T08:07:22","Operation":"AnalyzedByExternalApplication","OrganizationId":"f38a5ecd-2813-4862-b11b-ac1d563c806f","UserType":0,"UserKey":"3fee8456-6d20-4794-8219-5a7c381e965f","Workload":"PowerBI","UserId":"abcd@mail.com","ClientIP":"000.000.50.177","UserAgent":"MSOLAP 15.0 Client","Activity":"AnalyzedByExternalApplication","ItemName":"Other","DatasetName":"XYZ Driven Company","ObjectId":"Other","IsSuccess":true,"RequestId":"6836be8e-6e97-4bc9-a838-bf6e7b71e0c8","ActivityId":"7E92AE6A-F548-448D-93A8-6F5736DEA085"}
{"Id":"3a20c8a9-ef44-483a-b9c0-43e10deae9ae","RecordType":20,"CreationTime":"2019-09-14T08:07:20","Operation":"AnalyzedByExternalApplication","OrganizationId":"f38a5ecd-2813-4862-b11b-ac1d563c806f","UserType":0,"UserKey":"3fee8456-6d20-4794-8219-5a7c381e965f","Workload":"PowerBI","UserId":"abcd@mail.com","ClientIP":"000.000.50.177","UserAgent":"MSOLAP 15.0 Client","Activity":"AnalyzedByExternalApplication","ItemName":"Other","DatasetName":"XYZ Driven Company","ObjectId":"Other","IsSuccess":true,"RequestId":"02e5d772-057b-45b6-ae60-22b7fa610f98","ActivityId":"7E92AE6A-F548-448D-93A8-6F5736DEA085"}
```

I'm looking this data in another CSV file as below. Each value after ":" should insert into CSV as rows.

```
Id  RecordType  CreationTime    Operation   OrganizationId  UserType    UserKey Workload    UserId  ClientIP    UserAgent   Activity    ItemName    DatasetName ObjectId    IsSuccess   RequestId   ActivityId
ac325bc9-97f0-4b29-8fc4-90b80b945f6c    20  2019-09-14T08:07:22 AnalyzedByExternalApplication   f38a5ecd-2813-4862-b11b-ac1d563c806f    0   3fee8456-6d20-4794-8219-5a7c381e965f    PowerBI abcd@mail.com   000.000.50.177  MSOLAP 15.0 Client  AnalyzedByExternalApplication   Other   xyz Driven Company  Other   TRUE    6836be8e-6e97-4bc9-a838-bf6e7b71e0c8    7E92AE6A-F548-448D-93A8-6F5736DEA085
3a20c8a9-ef44-483a-b9c0-43e10deae9ae    20  2019-09-14T08:07:20 AnalyzedByExternalApplication   f38a5ecd-2813-4862-b11b-ac1d563c806f    0   3fee8456-6d20-4794-8219-5a7c381e965f    PowerBI abcd@mail.com   000.000.50.177  MSOLAP 15.0 Client  AnalyzedByExternalApplication   Other   XYZ Driven Company  Other   TRUE    02e5d772-057b-45b6-ae60-22b7fa610f98    7E92AE6A-F548-448D-93A8-6F5736DEA085
```

Correct data from CSV when opened in text editor.

"{""Id"":""ac325bc9-97f0-4b29-8fc4-90b80b945f6c"",""RecordType"":20,""CreationTime"":""2019-09-14T08:07:22"",""Operation"":""AnalyzedByExternalApplication"",""OrganizationId"":""f38a5ecd-2813-4862-b11b-ac1d563abchrf"",""UserType"":0,""UserKey"":""3fee8456-6d20-4794-8219-5a7c38abcdfe"",""Workload"":""Pxyswer"",""UserId"":""abcd@mail.com"",""ClientIP"":""123.456.50.177"",""UserAgent"":""MSOLAP 15.0 Client"",""Activity"":""AnalyzedByExternalApplication"",""ItemName"":""Other"",""DatasetName"":""ABCD Driven Company"",""ObjectId"":""Other"",""IsSuccess"":true,""RequestId"":""6836be8e-6e97-4bc9-a838-bf6e7b71e0c8"",""ActivityId"":""7E92AE6A-F548-448D-93A8-6F5736DEA085""}"

Comment: Please post the full code that threw the error (including how you import the csv)

Comment: Your is simply not valid, try an online json validator (e.g.: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and check/correct your json.

Comment: Your data, code and error message don't match. Please create a [mcve], test-run *that* code to make sure it still shows the behavior you're trying to debug, then [edit] your question and copy/paste *that* code along with representative sample data and the full error thrown by *that* code. Do not post code in comments, as that is unreadable.

Comment: I've pasted sample data here as I cant paste everything and also the code which I'm using to covert that JSON in CSV to columns in CSV.

Comment: The sample data you posted would give a different error than the one you showed, which would be clear to you had you actually followed the instructions I gave you. And I had already added the code from your previous comment to the question. No need to add it again.

Comment: My sample data in a CSV file and it's not a JSON file.I'm trying to parse JSON data in CSV as columns and save into different CSV file.Here am using Convert-FROM-JSON against my CSV file which giving be the error I pasted below. ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: "id" –

Comment: Are the leading `1.` and `2.` part of the input file, or did you add them in your question to indicate the row number?

Comment: No 1 and 2 are not part of the input file.I just mentioned them to make it more clear thats it

Comment: Then the code in my answer already does what you're asking. You're welcome.

Comment: I ran below code but it's still failing with error                                                                  code                                                                                                                            $properties='Id','RecordType','CreationTime','Operation','OrganizationId','UserType','UserKey','Workload','UserId','ClientIP','UserAgent','Activity','ItemName','DatasetName','ObjectId','IsSuccess','RequestId','ActivityId'

Get-Content $input_file |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object $properties |
    Export-Csv $output_file -NoType

Comment: Error:                                                                                                   
 ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: Id"":""ac325bc9-97f0-4b29-8fc4-90b80b945f6c"",""RecordType"":20,""CreationTime"":""2019-09-14T08:07:22"",""Operation"":""AnalyzedByExt
ernalApplication"",""OrganizationId"":""f38a5ecd-2813-4862-b11b-ac1d563c806f"",""UserType"":0,""UserKey"":""3fee8456-6d20-4794-8219-5a7c381e965f"",""Workload"":""PowerBI"",""Use
rId"":""abcd@mail.com"",""ClientIP"":""000.000.50.177"",""UserAgent"":""MSOLAP 15.0

Answer (score 0):

If your input file contains just that single example data row the code you posted will work. If the input file contains multiple statements like that your code will not work, because it'd be invalid JSON data.

Valid JSON:

```json
{"Id":"value","RecordType":"value","CreationTime":"value","Operation":"value"}
```

Valid JSON:

```json
[
{"Id":"value","RecordType":"value","CreationTime":"value","Operation":"value"},
{"Id":"value","RecordType":"value","CreationTime":"value","Operation":"value"}
]
```

Invalid JSON:

```json
{"Id":"value","RecordType":"value","CreationTime":"value","Operation":"value"}
{"Id":"value","RecordType":"value","CreationTime":"value","Operation":"value"}
```

To convert the latter kind of input data you need to convert each row as a separate JSON document:

```bsh
$properties = 'Id', 'RecordType', 'CreationTime', 'Operation'
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.csv' |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object $properties |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

To export all input fields except particular ones you'd define the properties to exclude rather than the ones to include:

```bsh
$exclude = 'foo', 'bar'
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.csv' |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object -Properties * -Exclude $exclude |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

---

**Edit:**

Apparently your input file is a CSV with only one column and no header, so you can import it via `Import-Csv`, but you need to specify the column header yourself. Expand the field to get the individual JSON values, then proceed as described above.

```bsh
$properties = 'Id', 'RecordType', 'CreationTime', 'Operation'
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' -Header foo |
    Select-Object -Expand foo |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object $properties |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

If you want all JSON values exported, simply omit the `Select-Object $properties` step.

Comment: Thanks for the update.I'll try this and post back if any issues.

Comment: Unfortunately the data into CSV is not in the format that you mentioned.Rather it's like this only.I just posted couple of rows but file contains hundreds of rows like this in CSV  
{"Id":"value","RecordType":"value","CreationTime":"value","Operation":"value"}
{"Id":"value","RecordType":"value","CreationTime":"value","Operation":"value"}

Comment: Here is the more details about smaple data.Column "AuditData" of a csv file contains below data       {"Id":"value","RecordType":value,"CreationTime":"value","Operation":"value","OrganizationId":"value","UserType":value,"UserKey":"value","Workload":"value","UserId":"value","ClientIP":"value","UserAgent":"value","Activity":"value","ItemName":"value","DatasetName":"value","ObjectId":"Other","IsSuccess":value,"RequestId":"value"}             And I'm looking to remove that Auditdata as column name and make each properties column and value as its corresponding value like below in another csv file

Comment: @AnilKumar Look, I cannot help you unless you provide a representative sample of your input data. One that actually reflects the structure of the input file, not just a single value of a single field. Edit your question to do so.

Comment: @AnilKumar The error message from your last comment clearly shows that your input data is not what you claim it is. Please open the input file in a text editor and copy/paste the first 3 lines from that file into your question.

Comment: @Ansgar..you're correct.When I open first few lines of CSV in text editor I see some extra quotes for each propery and vales.Here is the first row.Posting the data into question area

Comment: This is not CSV, this is more like a JSON stream.  [`jq`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-jq/) can be used to reformat this,